# How do I create an onHover action in material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am working with [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) and trying to implement a highlight to the row I am currently hovering over.

The [documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling) only provide a color change on a `onRowClick` action in the 3rd example:

```
function SelectedRowStyling() {
  const { useState } = React;
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Selected Row Styling Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      onRowClick={((evt, selectedRow) => setSelectedRow(selectedRow.tableData.id))}
      options={{
        rowStyle: rowData => ({
          backgroundColor: (selectedRow === rowData.tableData.id) ? '#EEE' : '#FFF'
        })
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

I read the available `props` in the source code and did not found anything like `onRowHover`. Tried some `ThemeProvider` solutions but did not manage to make it work, how could I implement the color change with the hover action?

Comment: If you provide the onRowClick, the hover action will also work out of the box.

Comment: @Domino987 I though about doing that but providing a onRowClick action causes the mouse pointer to become the "clicking hand" with no real action attached to the onRowClick, causing a bad UI/UX behavior, the user will think that by clicking the row something would happen when it won't.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following example using the approach provided here [enter link description here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1894) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1870)

[image]

I think the key is to overwritte Row component to gain access to onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events:

```
components={{
      Row: props => {
        return (
          <MTableBodyRow
            {...props}
            onMouseEnter={e => handleRowHover(e, props)}
            onMouseLeave={e => handleRowHoverLeave(e, props)}
          />
        );
      }
    }}
```

Also setting rowStyle option like this:

```
rowStyle: rowData => ({
        backgroundColor:
          rowData.tableData.id === hoveringOver ? "#0471ff" : ""
      })
```

Here is the complete sample code:

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import MaterialTable, { MTableBodyRow } from "material-table";

export default function CustomEditComponent(props) {
const [hoveringOver, setHoveringOver] = useState("");

const tableColumns = [
    { title: "Client", field: "client", width: "40%" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name", width: "40%" },
    { title: "Year", field: "year", width: "20%" }
];

const tableData = [
    {
    client: "client1",
    name: "Mary",
    year: "2019"
    },
    {
    client: "client2",
    name: "Joe",
    year: "2018"
    },
    {
    client: "client3",
    name: "Kal",
    year: "2019"
    },
    {
    client: "client4",
    name: "Dal",
    year: "2012"
    }
];

const handleRowHover = (event, propsData) => setHoveringOver(propsData.index);

const handleRowHoverLeave = (event, propsData) => setHoveringOver("");

return (
    <Fragment>
    <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={tableData}
        title="Material Table sample"
        options={{
        tableLayout: "fixed",
        search: false,
        rowStyle: rowData => ({
            backgroundColor:
            rowData.tableData.id === hoveringOver ? "#0471ff" : ""
        })
        }}
        components={{
        Row: props => {
            return (
            <MTableBodyRow
                {...props}
                onMouseEnter={e => handleRowHover(e, props)}
                onMouseLeave={e => handleRowHoverLeave(e, props)}
            />
            );
        }
        }}
    />
    </Fragment>
);
}
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-row-onhover-2lp1l?file=/src/App.js). I hope this works for you!

Comment: Hi Nico! Thanks for the answer! The issue I'm having with this approach is that it changes the state every time I enter or leave a row, rendering every table element again, when working with a lot of data, it becomes very laggy and do not perform well

Comment: I get it, I'll update if I find an alternative. Maybe working with refs, I'm not really sure.

Comment: I have the same problem. it works, but with 100+ rows it is not usable unfortunately