# How do I get hover effect on rows with material-table react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, material-table

I have used material-table with react to render my data. I want to show the hover effect and cursor pointer effect when I hover on rows. But I couldn't find this even in the documentation.

**IN SHORT-** I want to highlight some colors on a row when the cursor hovers to that row.

**Note:** I also found a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938378/how-do-i-create-an-onhover-action-in-material-table), but they used another state just to hover which downgrades the performance if I increase the data like thousands rows. Hence it's bad practice so here I am asking for alternate solutions for the same.

Here is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-frog-2ju61?file=/src/App.js)

Below I also pasted my code.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'

const empList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Neeraj", email: 'neeraj@gmail.com', phone: 9876543210, city: "Bangalore" },
  { id: 2, name: "Raj", email: 'raj@gmail.com', phone: 9812345678, city: "Chennai" },
  { id: 3, name: "David", email: 'david342@gmail.com', phone: 7896536289, city: "Jaipur" },
  { id: 4, name: "Vikas", email: 'vikas75@gmail.com', phone: 9087654321, city: "Hyderabad" },
]

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(empList)
  const columns = [
    { title: "ID", field: "id", editable: false },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    { title: "Email", field: "email" },
    { title: "Phone Number", field: 'phone', },
    { title: "City", field: "city", }
  ]


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <h4 align='center'>Material Table with CRUD operation</h4>
      <MaterialTable
        title="Employee Data"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: (newRow) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const updatedRows = [...data, { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), ...newRow }]
            setTimeout(() => {
              setData(updatedRows)
              resolve()
            }, 2000)
          }),
          onRowDelete: selectedRow => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const index = selectedRow.tableData.id;
            const updatedRows = [...data]
            updatedRows.splice(index, 1)
            setTimeout(() => {
              setData(updatedRows)
              resolve()
            }, 2000)
          }),
          onRowUpdate:(updatedRow,oldRow)=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            const index=oldRow.tableData.id;
            const updatedRows=[...data]
            updatedRows[index]=updatedRow
            setTimeout(() => {
              setData(updatedRows)
              resolve()
            }, 2000)
          })

        }}
        options={{
          actionsColumnIndex: -1, addRowPosition: "first"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the [Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) component?

Comment: @MikeK If I use table component then I have to write a lot of code just for crud operations and this material;-table solves this issue by providing all such things out of the box

Comment: If you're already using Material UI in your React project, adding marerial-table as a separate library, (that Material UI uses under the hood anyway), doesn't make any sense and it just bloats your project. You should read the documentation for the Table component, as it's pretty simple and you wouldn't have to write any more code than you would with marerial-table, really.

Comment: @MikeK actually I was saying like in material-table if I want to edit a row I just use actions property which provides me with the ability to edit entire row of data. But how can the same thing be achieved in the material UI table? Please open my code sandbox and click on edit Icon you'll understand my concern :-)

Comment: Making the [Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) component editable isn't an issue. A 3 second Google search led me to [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-editable-tables-wsp0c?codemirror=1)

Comment: @MikeK Thank you so much for your guidance, I also saw the same recently so I removed the material-table library and started implementing MUI Table. But the credit goes to you I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in your inside of your CSS

```
    tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```